# R - Access to formula variables

Tags: r, loops, text, character, plyr

I need to perform a loop over each variable of a formula. My formula is:

```
> lr$formula
target ~ grupoAntig + nu_seguros_1TRUNC + cd_sexo + grupoEdad + 
    vl_limite_aeQU + vl_ltd_6QU + Revolv3 + nu_servicios_1TRUNC + 
    fl_cliente_hit + nu_resumen_6 + fl_rv
```

I want to run a ddply for each variable. Like the following for 'grupoAntig':

```
> ddply(muestra, .(grupoAntig), summarise, ratioTarget=sum(target)/length(target))
  grupoAntig ratioTarget
1      20a40  0.01038062
2        h20  0.01201201
3        m40  0.00785325
```

So I started creating a list of variables by doing:

```
formula<-gsub(" ", "",as.character(lr$formula))
vars<-unlist(strsplit(formula, "[+]"))
```

If I choose vars[3] I get:

```
> vars[3]
[1] "grupoAntig"
```

And in ddply (plyr library) I need to introduce the variable name with no semicolons. So I tried:

```
> as.name(vars[3])
grupoAntig
```

But when I try it inside ddply:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(muestra, .(as.name(vars[3])), summarise, ratioTarget=sum(target)/length(target))
```

I get an error message:

> Error in unique.default(x) :

How can I use each variable name in ddply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to tangle with `gsub()` and `strsplit()` to get the values from the formula.  You can get all the formula variables with `all.vars()`.

```
x <- target ~ grupoAntig + nu_seguros_1TRUNC + cd_sexo + grupoEdad + 
    vl_limite_aeQU + vl_ltd_6QU + Revolv3 + nu_servicios_1TRUNC + 
    fl_cliente_hit + nu_resumen_6 + fl_rv

all.vars(x)
#  [1] "target"              "grupoAntig"          "nu_seguros_1TRUNC"  
#  [4] "cd_sexo"             "grupoEdad"           "vl_limite_aeQU"     
#  [7] "vl_ltd_6QU"          "Revolv3"             "nu_servicios_1TRUNC"
# [10] "fl_cliente_hit"      "nu_resumen_6"        "fl_rv"
```

Furthermore, you can use character names in `ddply()` so there's no need for `.()` or `as.name()` there.  From `?ddply` -

> **.variables**
>   variables to split data frame by, as `as.quoted` variables, a formula or character vector

Here's an example with `mtcars`.

```
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, sumMpg = sum(mpg))
#   cyl sumMpg
# 1   4  293.3
# 2   6  138.2
# 3   8  211.4
```

Same as

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, sumMpg = sum(mpg))
#   cyl sumMpg
# 1   4  293.3
# 2   6  138.2
# 3   8  211.4
```